# Why do libraries need to be linked?

Tags: c++, c, linker

When I have a single C file for example, `example.c` and I need to use a method from a library, let's say `math.h`, at the top of my `example.c` I will have `#include <math.h>` and during the preprocessor stage it will take the function declarations out of `math.h` and place them into my `math.c`. The file will then be compiled and at this stage I will have an object file with an empty memory address pointing to the function I could be using inside `math.h`, let us says `ceil`. Only during the linking stage will the reference to the function `ceil` from the `math.h` library be corrected placed so that it can use the function correctly.

However, suppose I am writing the function `ceil` and I created my own `math.c` and `math.h` files, why does it need to be linked when I do not necessarily need to reference anything. Suppose inside my `math.c` I create a function `add`, that very simply, returns the addition of two given parameters, I don
't need to import anything, I don't reference anything, I have a very simple library with one function that adds two numbers, what exactly will happen during the linking stage when making my library?

Comment: "why does it need to be linked". Linked to what? If something uses your `math.c` functions then it needs to link in that object. If something doesn't need anything from your `math.c` then it doesn't need to link it in. It's not clear what you are really asking.

Comment: @kaylum From what I have read, the three steps in the process to creating an executable is preprocessing -> compilation -> linking. However, if I made a `math.c` does that not reference anything outside of it's own file, however, many other files such as `example.c` will reference and use `math.c`, what happens or why does `math.c` need to be linked at all given that it includes one function that can perform it's tasks from the basic operations available in the language, i.e `x + y`